# Using Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly in .netstandard1.6 class library

Tags: dynamics-crm, .net-core, .net-standard

Are Dynamics CRM SDK assemblies compatible with the new .netstandard1.6 or older standards? I'm trying to use the Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly nuget package in a .netstandard class library. Are there any plans to make those libraries compatible with .netstandard 1.6 or 2.0 in future. Could not find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Why don't you drum up a simple console app, reference the sdk assemblies with the intended target .net version and try building the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently no they only support [.net 4.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly/). They may support .netstandard at some point in the future, but that would be speculation.

An easy way to tell currently is by looking at the NuGet package page and checking dependencies. For example another package [CSVHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/2.16.3) supports .netstandard

[image]

While the [SDK tooling package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly/) does not

[image]